# Wiring.h missing in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm using the DateTime Library example project, but when I try to compile it, I get the following error message:

```
Arduino: 1.8.0 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

/Users/Luke/Documents/Arduino/libraries/DateTime/DateTime.cpp:15:20: fatal error: wiring.h: No such file or directory
 #include <wiring.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Please help, as this is ridiculously irritating!

Answer (score 5):

You have two problems, I'll list solutions to them:

## Root problem

Arduino's DateTime library is out of date, upgrade to the [Time](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time) library. You can install it from the library manager, there is no need for dodgy .zip files.

## DateTime problem

The Arduino environment does not include a `wiring.h` file, it was renamed to `wiring_private.h`. You should replace all references to `wiring.h` with `wiring_private.h`.

Using `grep -rnw '.' -e "wiring.h"` in the DateTime folder I can only find one reference to `wiring.h`. So change line 15 in `DateTime.cpp` from:

```
#include <wiring.h>
```

to:

```
#include <wiring_private.h>
```